# Reading a .GPB file in C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, gis, postgis

I have a .GPB file, I need to extract the common GPS data from it but I don't find a clear structure that specify the contents of that file.

as a sample record from file

00000260     02 11 A9 61 E7 96 C4 95 B6 86 CA 01 9A 09 DC 01

how can i go through this file to get my data, I searched alot and found that it called "Dell Axim Navigation System (.gpb) file format".

Regards,

m.sai

Comment: I can't answer this exactly, but you could play around with [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org) to see if you can work it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Extensions&referringTitle=Documentation) probably supports what you need